# How to setup permission to run unix executable file in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, macos, shell, terminal, permissions

I am trying to run a unix executable file (fet scheduler) in my Flutter app running on MacOS. At first I am checking if the executable file exists in application support directory. If not, the app downloads the file in that folder. Then, I am trying to run the following command:

```
Process.start('$directory/fet-cl', params);
```

The "directory" variable targets "/Users/:username:/Library/Containers/com.myApp.myApp/Data/Library/Application Support/com.myApp.myApp" and "params" variable has the necessary options for fet-cli to work.

But I am getting the following error:
"Unhandled Exception: ProcessException: Permission denied"

How can I run this command with a proper permission in Flutter on MacOS? Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

maybe i'm arriving too late but, if you need to run an executable on macos, you need to disable **sandboxing**.
To disable sandbox mode, change the false key to true in `macos/Runner/*.entitlements` `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` files sections:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package [process_run](https://pub.dev/packages/process_run), Which will give more features and more guides to permissions in MacOS.